# how to get the date from string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string like

```
 string startdatestring = "2017-03-10T07:19:28.907";
 DateTime firstdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdatestring,
                                          "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 var firstDateString = firstdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

want the output only `2017-03-10`

Comment: not able to get if you will help me it will be fine

Comment: Your input date doesn't match your format string...

Comment: The pattern you are telling the parser to expect (`yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`) and the pattern of the date you are passing are not the same.

Comment: so could you tell me the format what i have to write

Comment: Something like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` might do the trick.

Comment: @npinti sounds correct the reason is that `DateTime.ParseExact()` will parse for the specific format you give it. Right now your initial string date does not match your format inside the `DateTime.ParseExact()`. If the date contains "-" in between the values your MUST put "-" not "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like below

```
string startdatestring = "2017-03-10T07:19:28.907";
//1st way - Convert.ToDatetime works properly
//DateTime firstdate = Convert.ToDateTime(startdatestring);
//2nd way - DateTime.Parse also works perfect
//DateTime firstdate = DateTime.Parse(startdatestring);
//3rd way - DateTime.ParseExact also works perfect
DateTime firstdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdatestring,
                                 "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var firstDateString = firstdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine(firstDateString);
```

### OUTPUT

2017-03-10

Answer (score 0):

Your input string `"2017-03-10T07:19:28.907"` doesn't match the format string `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`.

Considering your input is already in a standard format, you can use `DateTime.Parse`:

```
var firstdate = DateTime.Parse(startdatestring);
```

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime firstdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdatestring,
>                                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",
>                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

it's yyyy-MM-dd instead of yyyy/MM/dd

;)

Answer (score 0):

### Change you code as below

```
  DateTime firstdate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdatestring,
                                 "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 string startdatestring = "2017-03-10T07:19:28.907";
 string s = startdatestring.Substring(0, 9);
```